# Measure WebGL texture load in ms

Tags: javascript, webgl

How can i measure WebGL texture load in milliseconds?

Right now I have an array of images that will be renderd out as a map using a game loop and im interested in capturing the time it takes for WebGL to load every texture image in milliseconds. I wonder how that can be done to measure this because JavaScript is not synchronous with WebGL.

Comment: How will this help you? Will you be checking the million variations of machines and drivers out there? For example how long it takes to upload a texture on a Nexus 5 running Android 5.0.1 vs 5.0.2 vs a Samung Galaxy Note 6 running different OSes vs every model of iPhone, iPad, on each OS plus every model of Mac wtih different OSes and then all the various windows machines with different cpus, different gpus, different drivers, etc....

I ask because whatever problem you're trying to solve it's not clear how measuring upload time on 1 machine will help

Comment: it is a research work that I do. I need that kind of data from a webgl test application that I have built.

Comment: You still haven't answered my question. What's the point of this data? If you get 1ms answer how will that help you as it will be useless for other machines and there is no way from JavaScript to find out what kind of machine the user is on.

Comment: Tests runs on a specific device. Measurements are made on a specific scenario in both Canvas and WebGL graphics. Many requests will be made and context switching will maybe be a cost for WebGL. It is a part of the research I do. It is not relevant to know what the research is about for this question i have about measurements to the GPU.

Comment: It is relevant because the answer will be useless for 99.999999% of all use cases. You're in a browser which runs on over a million combinations of hardware. Even native games don't do this. They just let the user choose various graphic options because there's too much variation to know if something is going to be too slow.

Comment: There is one type of hardware in this case as i mentioned. Other devices are not interesting. I have a certain amount of data that will be sent down to the GPU level and the question is how will this affect the amount of data over time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to measure any timing in WebGL is to figure out how much work you can do in a certain amount of time. Pick a target speed, say 30fps, use requestAnimationFrame, keep increasing the work until you're over the target.

```
var targetSpeed  = 1/30;
var amountOfWork = 1;

var then = 0;
function test(time) {
   time *= 0.001;  // because I like seconds 

   var deltaTime = time - then;
   then = time;

   if (deltaTime < targetTime) {
     amountOfWork += 1;
   }

   for (var ii = 0; ii < amountOfWork; ++ii) {
     doWork();
   }

   requestAnimationFrame(test);
}
requestAnimationFrame(test);
```

It's not quite that simple because the browsers, at least in my experience, don't seem to give a really stable timing for frames.

Caveats

1. Don't assume requestAnimationFrame will be at 60fps.

   There are plenty of devices that run faster (VR) or slower (low-end hd-dpi monitors).
2. Don't measure time to start emitting commands until the time you stop

   Measure the time since the last requestAnimationFrame. WebGL just
   inserts commands into a buffer. Those commands execute in the driver
   possibly even in another process so

   ```
   var start = performance.now;         // WRONG!
   gl.someCommand(...);                 // WRONG!
   gl.flush(...);                       // WRONG!
   var time = performance.now - start;  // WRONG!
   ```
3. Actually use the resource.

   Many resources are lazily initialized so just uploading a resource 
   but not using it will not give you an accurate measurement. You'll
   need to actually do a draw with each texture you upload. Of course
   make it small 1 pixel 1 triangle draw, with a simple shader. The
   shader must actually access the resource otherwise the driver 
   my not do any lazy initialization.
4. Don't assume different types/sizes of textures will have proportional
   changes in speed.

   Drivers to different things. For example some GPUs might not support
   anything but RGBA textures. If you upload a LUMINANCE texture the
   driver will expand it to RGBA. So, if you timed using RGBA textures
   and assumed a LUMINANCE texture of the same dimensions would upload
   4x as fast you'd be wrong

   Similarly don't assume different size textures will upload at
   speed proportional to their sizes. Internal buffers of drivers
   and other limits mean that difference sizes might take differnent
   paths.

   In other words you can't assume 1024x1024 texture will upload
   4x as slow as a 512x512 texture.
5. Be aware even this won't promise real-world results

   By this I mean for example if you're on tiled hardware (iPhone
   for example) then the way the GPU works is to gather all of
   the drawing commands, separate them into tiles, cull any
   draw that are invisible and only draw what's left where as
   most desktop GPUs draw every pixel of every triangle.

   Because a tiled GPU
   does everything at the end it means if you keep uploading
   data to the same texture and draw between each upload it will
   have to keep copies of all your textures until it draws.
   Internally there might be some point at which it flushes and
   draws what it has before buffering again.

   Even a desktop driver wants to pipeline uploads so you upload
   contents to texture B, draw, upload new contents to texture B,
   draw. If the driver is in the middle of doing the first drawing
   it doesn't want to wait for the GPU so it can replace the contents.
   Rather it just wants to upload the new contents somewhere else
   not being used and then when it can point the texture to the new
   contents.

   In normal use this isn't a problem because almost no one uploads
   tons of textures all the time. At most they upload 1 or 2 video
   frames or 1 or 2 procedurally generated textures. But when you're
   benchmarking you're stressing the driver and making it do things
   it won't actually be doing normally. In the example above it might
   assume a texture is unlikely to be uploaded 10000 times a frame
   you'll hit a limit where it has to freeze the pipeline until 
   some of your queued up textures are drawn. That freeze will make
   your result appear slower than what you'd really get in normal
   use cases.

   The point being you might benchmark and get told it takes 5ms 
   to upload  a texture but in truth it only takes 3ms, you just
   stalled pipeline many times which outside your benchmark is 
   unlikely to happen.